# Sublime Text 2 Build System custom rake task

Tags: ruby, github, rake, sublimetext2, build-script

I am using rake and the git_repositoy gem to deploy my rails app to github. The rake task i use looks like the following:

```
task :test_deploy, :message do | t, args|
    @git = GitRepository.new
    Rake::Task[:test].invoke
    commit(args.message,@git)
    Rake::Task[:push_to_origin].invoke
    Rake::Task[:deploy_to_heroku].invoke
end



task :push_to_origin do
    @git.push
end

def commit(message,git_repository)
        if(git_repository.has_untracked?)
                git_repository.add
        end
        if(git_repository.has_changes?)
                git_repository.commit(:message => message, :options => "-a")
        end
end
```

So when i call rake i do it in the following way `rake test_deploy['my commit message']`.
I want to be able to do this with a sublime build task that prompts me for a message and executes it. Does anyone know to get sublime to give me a message box prompt for a build task?

Thanks,

Ben